# Why can't I POST /login with Node and Passport?

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, passport.js, passport-local

I am setting up Passport with Node/Express app (with MongoDB). For some reason I am unable to POST to /login. Strangely, the BasicStrategy instance I've set up isn't even running at all.

When I run it in Postman, I get the html file back. When I try it in the browser, for some reason I get a 200 response with the failureRedirect.

The strangest thing is that the strategy is not being called at all; the terminal console doesn't log any of the `console.log`s that I have set up whatsoever.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Here is my login router:

/users/routes/loginRouter.js

```
const {BasicStrategy} = require('passport-http'),
      express = require('express'),
      jsonParser = require('body-parser').json(),
      passport = require('passport');

const {User} = require('../models');

const loginRouter = express.Router();

loginRouter.use(jsonParser);

const strategy = new BasicStrategy(function(username, password, callback) {
  console.log(arguments);
  let user;
  User
    .findOne({username: username})
    .exec()
    .then(_user => {
      console.log(_user);
      user = _user;
      if (!user) {
        return callback(null, false, {message: 'Incorrect username'});
      }
      return user.validatePassword(password);
    })
    .then(isValid => {
      console.log(isValid);
      if (!isValid) {
        return callback(null, false, {messsage: 'Incorrect password'});
      }
      else {
        return callback(null, user)
      }
    });
});

passport.use(strategy);
loginRouter.use(passport.initialize());

loginRouter.post('/',
  passport.authenticate('basic',
    {
      session: true,
      successRedirect: '/console',
      failureRedirect: '/login'
    }
  )
);

module.exports = {loginRouter};
```

Now this is my server file:

/server.js

```
const express = require('express'),
      bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
      mongoose = require('mongoose'),
      passport = require('passport');

const {adminRouter} = require('./users/routes/adminRouter'),
      {loginRouter} = require('./users/routes/loginRouter'),
      {registerRouter} = require('./users/routes/registerRouter'),
      {PORT, DATABASE_URL} = require('./config'),
      {router} = require('./router');


const app = express();
const path = require('path');

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use('/api/users/', registerRouter);
app.use('/login', loginRouter);
app.use('/console', adminRouter);

app.use('/', router);

app.get(['/login', '/register', '/about', '/archive', '/maxim/:maximId', '/console'], (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'))});


function runServer(databaseUrl=DATABASE_URL, port=PORT) {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    mongoose.connect(databaseUrl, err => {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err);
      }
      server = app.listen(port, () => {
        console.log(`Your app is listening on port ${port}`);
        resolve();
      })
      .on('error', err => {
        mongoose.disconnect();
        reject(err);
      });
    });
  });
}

function closeServer() {
  return mongoose.disconnect().then(() => {
     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       console.log('Closing server');
       server.close(err => {
         if (err) {
           return reject(err);
         }
         resolve();
       });
     });
  });
}

if (require.main === module) {
  runServer().catch(err => console.error(err));
};

module.exports = {app, runServer, closeServer};
```

My other routes are working perfectly fine, for example this register route is functioning as expected:

/users/routes/registerRouter.js

```
const {BasicStrategy} = require('passport-http'),
      express = require('express'),
      jsonParser = require('body-parser').json(),
      passport = require('passport');

const {User} = require('../models');

const registerRouter = express.Router();

registerRouter.use(jsonParser);

const strategy = new BasicStrategy(
  (username, password, cb) => {
    User
      .findOne({username})
      .exec()
      .then(user => {
        if (!user) {
          return cb(null, false, {
            message: 'No such user'
          });
        }
        if (user.password !== password) {
          return cb(null, false, 'Incorrect password');
        }
        return cb(null, user);
      })
      .catch(err => cb(err))
});

passport.use(strategy);

registerRouter.post('/', (req, res) => {
  if (!req.body) {
    return res.status(400).json({message: 'No request body'});
  }

  if (!('username' in req.body)) {
    return res.status(422).json({message: 'No username in request body'});
  }

  let {username, password, email} = req.body;

  if (typeof username !== 'string') {
    return res.status(422).json({message: 'Incorrect field type: username'});
  }

  username = username.trim();

  if (username === '') {
    return res.status(422).json({message: 'Incorrect field length: username'});
  }

  if (!(password)) {
    return res.status(422).json({message: 'No password in request body'});
  }

  if (typeof password !== 'string') {
    return res.status(422).json({message: 'Incorrect field type: password'});
  }

  password = password.trim();

  if (password === '') {
    return res.status(422).json({message: 'Incorrect field length: password'});
  }

  if (typeof email !== 'string') {
    return res.status(422).json({message: 'Incorrect field type: email'});
  }

  email = email.trim();

  if (email === '') {
    return res.status(422).json({message: 'Incorrect field length: email'});
  }

  // check for existing user
  return User
    .find({username})
    .count()
    .exec()
    .then(count => {
      if (count > 0) {
        return res.status(422).json({message: 'Username taken'});
      }
      // if no existing user, hash password
      return User.hashPassword(password)
    })
    .then(hash => {
      return User
        .create({
          username: username,
          password: hash,
          email: email
        })
    })
    .then(user => {
      return res.status(201).json(user.apiRep());
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).json({message: 'Internal Server Error'})
    });
});

module.exports = {registerRouter};
```

Comment: Here is the GitHub repo for easier reference (the branch is `passport-refactor`): https://github.com/jhwheeler/simple-spirit

Comment: Try adding a `console.log()` in the strategy in `registerRouter.js` and see if _that_ gets called for `/login`

Comment: I added a `console.log(req.body)` to the strategy in `registerRouter.js`, on the first line of the function block, and it only gets called when I hit `/api/users` (the route for registration); it doesn't get  called when I hit `/login`.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if you should call `loginRouter.use(passport.initialize())`, because you're also initializing Passport in `server.js`.

Comment: Good point. I removed it, but still have the same issue.

Comment: And still it's not the other strategy that gets called? Because if you use the same strategy twice without explicitly naming them, you may overwrite the first one that gets "used".

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean - so the fact that they're in different files doesn't change the namespaces? I assumed that even though I called both `strategy`, by having them in separate files, I could avoid any naming conflicts. But in any regard, no it didn't call the other one. In the end I've decided to ditch Passport and write my own authenticator (so far it's working much smoother!).

Comment: `passport` is a singleton during the lifetime of your app, so it's shared across all files.